# How to open a setting activity on quick settings tile long click

Tags: android, android-quick-settings

As per what [official doc](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/quicksettings-tiles#launch_an_activity) says, you can override a custom quick setting tile's default long press behavior:

> Long-tapping a tile prompts the App Info screen for the user. To override this behavior and instead launch an activity for setting preferences, add an `<intent-filter>` to one of your activities with [ACTION_QS_TILE_PREFERENCES](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/quicksettings/TileService.html?utm_campaign=adp_series_quicksettingstiles_092916&utm_source=medium&utm_medium=blog#ACTION_QS_TILE_PREFERENCES).

However this is only possible for the tile's owner app. Is it possible instead, to open a third-party activity - specially a device setting page - on quick tile being long pressed?

Answer (score 0):

you could create an intent and set its component name to whatever activity you wanna launch.
ie:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN,)

intent.setComponentName(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.apps.search.weather.WeatherExportedActivity")

startActivity(intent)
```

ofcourse this requires you to know the activity name

Comment: Should we implement explicit intent in this case?